# The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 has terminated on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 has terminated on android studio
this error happens with me when I try to run empty app android studio

I try to run the empty app
and I expected to run the app

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.